# How to convert the time entered in django admin into utc?

Tags: python, django, django-timezone

There are a lot of questions here on SO to make `Django-Admin` `time aware` and all related stuff. But I couldn't get help from the existing ones. So I am asking a new one with a slightly different intent.

I want that when a user enters some data via the `admin` specifically when he is entering the `date` and `time` he is obviously entering it in his `local time`, that is the `system time`. I want that the admin should convert it into `UTC` before storing it in the DB. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

If running in a Windows environment this must be set to the same as your system time zone.

```
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Los_Angeles'
```

Define it like this in your settings.py
And replace the time zone according to you .

Comment: I am on `Linux`. And the problem is that a `superuser` could be anywhere in the world. So if he is using the `admin` from some other place with a different time zone, and he uses the `widget` to say insert the date and time as the `today` and `now` times, then this will get stored in the db in his/her `local time`. I want it be stored as in `UTC`.